# UWP How to allow a user to swipe through a rotator tile?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Im fairly new to UWP an have the following code below I got off the UWP toolkit samples Github.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:RotatorTile">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:RotatorTile">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="Scroller"
                            DataContext="{x:Null}">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="Stack">
                            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translate" Y="0" />
                            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Current"
                                              Content="{Binding}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                                              DataContext="{x:Null}" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Next"
                                              Content="{Binding}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                                              DataContext="{x:Null}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="RotationDelay" Value="0:0:5" />
    <Setter Property="ExtraRandomDuration" Value="0:0:5" />
</Style>
```

This is code to basically display a slideshow of images in Microsofts tile style of UI. I want to be able to give the user the ability to control the tiles by swiping left or right as apposed to it moving on time passed.

Comment: The RotatorTile does not have this capability built in. I suggest you make a request in the issues repo, and we can take a look at making that possible.

Comment: A FlipView might work for you.